# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [164309, 109541]

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I've built a machine learning model from 2 data frames called `df_test` and `df_train` for naive Bayes, I run it with this code in my pycharm, but when I run it with this model, it returns:

> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [164309, 109541].

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    
    # Split dataset into training set and test set
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_train.drop(columns = ['Interest_Rate']), df_test, test_size=1.0,random_state=109) # 70% training and 30% test
    
    
    from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
    
    #Create a Gaussian Classifier
    gnb = GaussianNB()
    
    #Train the model using the training sets
    gnb.fit(X_train, y_train)
    
    #Predict the response for test dataset
    y_pred = gnb.predict(X_test)
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You want 70-30 split of your data but here you created 100% test data. Change `test_size` to 0.3(30%) instead of 1.0(100%).

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_train.drop(columns = ['Interest_Rate']), df_test, test_size=0.3,random_state=109) # 70% training and 30% test
```

Comment: idk but the process doesnt appear the error, but doesnt produce result too, the process has just stop

Comment: Does `y_pred` has values?

Comment: Can you give a Shape of `df_train` and `df_test`?

Comment: i already type print(df_test.shape())
print(df_train.shape()). but idk why it doesnt not produce a result